# Getting type error when invoking IIFE

Tags: javascript

i have written a function that logs the contents of an object, it works if i create the object then and there but does not work for already existing objects.
I am getting type error

```
    var content = {
    x: 5,
    y: 7
}

(objectData => { 
    for(let key of Object.keys(objectData)){
        console.log(`${key} : ${objectData[key]}`);
    }
})
(content);
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the error?  At first glance, this doesn't look quite right `key of Object.keys`

Comment: Just add `;` after the assignment of `content`

Comment: You're using `for ... of` when you should be using `for ... in`

Comment: You're missing a `;`: `var content = {x: 5, y: 7};`

Comment: It is also worth moving `(content)` up to the line before.  Otherwise, a semi colon might get injected at the end of the line.